# Object Destructuring from API in Vue3

Tags: javascript, object, vuejs2, state

I want to put the data from API to Vue state. What is the quick approach to do this?

```
getProjectData(id) {
      axios.get(`/api/project/${id}`).then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        /* I don't want to manually assign the value one by one (since the name is the same, there should be a quick way */
        this.formState.name = res.data.projects.name
        this.formState.stage = res.data.projects.stage
        this.formState.status = res.data.projects.status
        this.formState.description = res.data.projects.description
        this.formState.stations = res.data.projects.stations
      });
    },
```

Comment: `Object.assign(this.formState, res.data.projects)`

Comment: this.formState = {...res.data.projects}, Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spread operator to achieve it:

```
this.formState = {...res.data.projects}
```

To point out, these properties are copied shallowly. If a property value is an object, any **modification** made to it will reflect in the `res.data.projects` object.